# Is there a way to retrieve DoB from .net to Angular

Tags: angular, angularjs, typescript

Im trying to retrieve the Dob in that I stored it in database I looked through internet but I have zero idea how do it.

```
export class DetailsEmployeeComponent  implements OnInit{

  employeeDetail: Employee ={
    id: 0,
    firstName: '',
    dateOfBirth: new Date
 
  };
```

New Date will give the date-timezone

Answer (score 0):

1. Build a Web API to accept an HTTP request from your Angular app, get the value from your database and return the result
   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/
2. Use the Angular HttpClient to call your API to get the value https://angular.io/guide/http.

Comment: I already did everything and it works fine. regarding the Date of Birthday I don't know how to do it. I tried to dateOfBirth: Date(this.employeeDetail.DateOfBirth) --Not working

Comment: @owwoj - it's unclear what you mean by "not working."  The syntax in your comment is wrong - you'd need to use the "new" keyword like this:  "dateOfBirth: new Date(this.employeeDetail.DateOfBirth)".  Outside of that, what is the value of "this.employeeDetail.DateOfBirth" if you console log it?